# How can I extract a segment from a file name?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory of files with the following naming scheme:

```
<project name>-<group name>.txt
```

I want to extract `<group name>` from the files I am looping through:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *; do
    echo "group name: ${f}"
done
```

How can this be done? I am experimenting with `${f##...}` and `${f%...}` but without success so far. I am unsure if they can be combined, so I can first leave out the prefix `<project name>-` and then leave out the suffix `.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in *-*.txt; do
    # shortest match: a-b-c-d.txt => d
    [[ $file =~ ([^-]+).txt$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    # longest match: a-b-c-d.txt => b-c-d
    [[ $file =~ -(.+).txt$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

Comment: change to `/bin/bash`

Comment: I did not know about `BASH_REMATCH`, but this is what I needed. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @PesaThe The `bash` executable isn’t always in `/bin`. It’s usually more portable to use something like `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. (It’s also more portable to not use Bashisms, but since avoiding then is harder than typing 8 extra characters per script, they’re often worth the cost).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible in one line, but if you go in steps it's easy:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    base=${f%.txt}
    projectname=${base%-*}
    groupname=${base#*-}
    echo project name: $projectname
    echo group name: $groupname
done
```

If you're OK with calling an external program, this also works and is pretty readable.

```
for f in *.txt; do
    groupname=$(basename ${f#*-} .txt)
    echo group name: $groupname
done
```

Comment: Doing it in steps is clever, great, thank you. It would be awesome though if that could be written as a one-liner, as I only need the group name.

Comment: @Bradson If you were using zsh you could nest them: `groupname=${${f%-*}%.sql}`, but bash doesn't support this.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that.